# No compatible AVDs with target 'Google APIs'

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I am developing an android application and trying to launch it on an AVD. The API is set to Android 2.3.3. I have a 2.3.3 emulator (sdk version 10), and the android manifest reads:

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

I changed the target to 10 to match the api I have included in the project. How do I resolve this error:

```
[2013-01-30 23:18:47 - kiloboltandroidframework] Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Google APIs'.
[2013-01-30 23:18:48 - kiloboltandroidframework] Still no compatible AVDs with target 'Google APIs': Aborting launch.
```

Comment: There were so many great answers. I picked the one with the most votes. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While creating a new Android virtual device , select the **Target** as Google API - API Level 10

Answer (score 2):

Android Api level 10 is different from Google Api level 10. Android comes with only android.jar file white Google Api comes with android.jar as well as maps.jar. your project might require Google Api's and you haven't installed them. To Install Google Api's go to SDK Manager and check. If they are already installed, then create a AVD with Google Api level 10 platform.

Comment: i used 
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />  and installed Google API as well but still having same problem.

Comment: @SunishthaSingh create an AVD with Google API then try it.

Answer (score 1):

> Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Google APIs'.

=> Means that you haven't create any AVD with Google API, but yes you have implemented functionality which uses Google APIs, like Google Map.

Find in snap how to install Google API, soon after installing create an AVD with the same Google API.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an AVD that uses the Google APIs Add-on. See [here](https://developers.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/installing) .

Answer (score 0):

Start the other VM from VDM which has Target api is "Google APi" and Platform is 2.3.3. if your don't have any google api in your VDM (Virtual Device Manager) than please download it. Start that once And than run your project.